# suptitle Error using axes Invalid axes handle

Tags: matlab, histogram, subplot, suptitle

I am trying to create histograms in a loop. I am creating two figures and want a suptitle above them, but when I do that the title of the subplots doesn't work anymore . This is my code

```
suptitle('Observation')
for i=1:c:b
    i
    MagObs1=[];
    subplot(b,1,i);
    MagObs1=MagObs(:,i);%0 and 1s
    minMagObs1=min(MagObs1);
    MagObs2=MagObs1(MagObs1>0.001);
    h1=histogram(MagObs2,NumberBins,'Normalization','probability');
    title([num2str(DepthObs(i)),'m']);
    h1.BinLimits=[bottomVel topVel];
    xlabel('Current speed (m/s)');
    ylabel('Frequency');
end

figure(2);% clf;
suptitle('Model')
for i=1:c:b

    subplot(b,1,i);
    
    h2=histogram(MagMatrixH1(i,:),NumberBins,'Normalization','probability')
    title([num2str(DepthObs(i)),'m'])
    h2.BinLimits=[bottomVel topVel]
    xlabel('Current speed (m/s)')
    ylabel('Frequency')
end
```

and this is the error I get

```
Error using axes
Invalid axes handle

Error in suptitle (line 98)
axes(haold);

Error in Histogram (line 118)
suptitle('Observation')
```

This is my output. Normally, every figure has multiple histograms underneath each other, but for this example I only show one.
[image]

[image]

As you can see in the second picture. "Im" should be '300m', could you help me fix this subplots title?

Comment: In the (very little) documentation that `suptitle` has, it says: "Use this function
  after all subplot commands."

Comment: @AnderBiguri the bioinformatics toolbox if I recall correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the (very little) documentation that `suptitle` has, it says:

> "Use this function after all subplot commands."

Try adding it in the end of your plotting